# (Android4.2)random compile error "unrecognized command line option '-mshort-load-bytes'" with arm-eabi-gcc 4.6.x

Tags: android, u-boot

I have ported u-boot to my android4.2 source and use the android toolchain, 
which has a gcc version 4.6.x-google 20120106.

My environment for build: Ubuntu 10.04, with a host gcc version 4.4.3.

My platform is arm-v7, cotex-a5.

The problem is that sometimes u-boot will encounter the following compile error (I use a multijob for building android):

```
target thumb C++: libGLES_trace <= frameworks/native/opengl/libs/GLES_trace/src/gltrace_context.cpp

    CC  ispi.c

target thumb C++: libGLES_trace <= frameworks/native/opengl/libs/GLES_trace/src/gltrace_egl.cpp

    CC  spl.c

target thumb C++: libGLES_trace <= frameworks/native/opengl/libs/GLES_trace/src/gltrace_eglapi.cpp

    MAKE    arch/arm/lib/
    CC  timer.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-mshort-load-bytes'

make[2]: *** [/home/jenkins/workspace/droid-4.2.2_r1/out/target/product/aere/obj/u-boot/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/rda/timer.o] Error 1

make[1]: *** [/home/jenkins/workspace/droid-4.2.2_r1/out/target/product/aere/obj/u-boot/arch/arm/cpu/armv7/rda/librda.o] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jenkins/workspace/rdadroid-4.2.2_r1/u-boot'
make: *** [out/target/product/aere/obj/u-boot/u-boot.img] Error 2

make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

But if I build it again, the compile error disappears。

I know that GCC after 3.5 doesn't support the `-mshort-load-bytes` option, but my gcc-version
is 4.6, and I checked `include/generated/cc_options.mk`, if build fails, the content is:

```
CC_OPTIONS += -marm
CC_OPTIONS += -mno-thumb-interwork
CC_OPTIONS += -mabi=apcs-gnu
CC_OPTIONS += -mabi=aapcs-linux
CC_OPTIONS += -march=armv7-a
CC_OPTIONS += -fno-stack-protector
CC_OPTIONS += -Wno-format-nonliteral
CC_OPTIONS += -Wno-format-security
CC_OPTIONS += -fstack-usage
CC_OPTIONS += -fno-toplevel-reorder
CC_OPTIONS += -mshort-load-bytes
```

If success, there is no `CC_OPTIONS += -mshort-load-bytes`.

So, anyone can tell me how to debug this problems? 
thank you!

Comment: Following words is from android developer: "The Android build system isn't designed to use recursive calls to make, and the result in that case is subject to race conditions and therefore very undefined. 

You can try to build without -j, you can try to add the pseudo-target "showcommands" to your command line, but the real debugging is likely to be in the makefiles you're invoking recursively, not in the Android build system.

Comment: So, I build the android with two step: make bootloader(u-boot), then make -j32.  but I think this is just a workround, don't resolve the real bug.

Answer (score 0):

`-mshort-load-bytes` is an old option which has been replaced in GCC 3 by `-malignment-traps`. It only matters for old versions of ARM architecture, before ARMv4. It tells the GCC to not load `short` (2 byte) values by loading words (4 byte) values from an unaligned location, because that would cause an alignment trap.

References: [gcc 3.0.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/gcc_3.html#SEC27) and [gcc 2.95.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_2.html#SEC22) docs.